# How can I release my api for anyone to consume?

Tags: go, cors, go-gin

I have a server made in go, gin and libpq, my front end is trying to consume the api but it is giving an error..
this error:

```html
Access to fetch at 'https://--brapoio-t.azurewebsites.net/-/-o' from origin 'https://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

(the url was changed on purpose to ask the question here on stack overflow)

My project is divided like this:

main.go
routes:
//routes

main.go:

```
package main
```

import (
"os"

```
"github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
"github.com/guilherm5/brapoio/routes"
```

)

func main() {

```
Router := gin.New()
Router.Use(gin.LoggerWithWriter(gin.DefaultErrorWriter))

//tem toda minha parte de configuração
routes.ConfiguracaoSistema(Router)
routes.ConfiguracaoModulo(Router)
routes.ModuloSistema(Router)
routes.ArvoreMenu(Router)
routes.ModuloArvoreMenu(Router)

//tem toda minha parte de Usuario
routes.Usuario(Router)
routes.EmpresaUsuario(Router)
routes.CampoTabelaUsuario(Router)
routes.ProgramaUsuario(Router)
routes.FuncionalidadeProgramaUsuario(Router)
routes.TabelaUsuario(Router)
routes.ParametroFiltroTabelaUsuario(Router)
//meu servidor de autenticação
routes.JWTAutentication(Router)

listenAddr := ":1000"

if val, ok := os.LookupEnv("FUNCTIONS_CUSTOMHANDLER_PORT"); ok {
    listenAddr = ":" + val
}

Router.Run(listenAddr)
```

}

an example of package routes:

```html
package routes

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/guilherm5/brapoio/controllers"
)

//NAO ESQUECER DE FAZER AZURE

func ModuloSistema(c *gin.Engine) {
    c.GET("/api/moduloSistema", controllers.GetModuloSistema())
    c.GET("/api/moduloSistemaID", controllers.GetModuloSistemaID())
    c.POST("/api/moduloSistema", controllers.NewModuloSistema())
    c.PUT("/api/moduloSistema", controllers.UpdateModuloSistemao())
    c.DELETE("/api/moduloSistema", controllers.DeleteModuloSistema())
}
```

How can I solve this error that my front end has been getting?

Comment: anyone meaning *any website in the world*? or your own frontend? check [this](https://github.com/gin-contrib/cors) out. specifically `Default() allows all origins`

Comment: @Yarin_007 to solve my problem I prefer it to be any site in the world

Comment: okay, check out that link. it's about (as the error specifies), Same Origin Policy, and telling browsers they're allowed to send data to a different "space" using the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. try that config and if you have any further questions feel free to drop them here

Comment: OK thanks.
I will read the documentation and if doubts arise I will get back to you @Yarin_007

Answer (score 2):

I think first you should read about CORS to understand why it blocks your Frontend site to access the resources. You can read [this doc from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) for more detail. For your case with Gin, you can add [CORS middleware](https://github.com/gin-contrib/cors) to enable it.

Comment: No, CORS doesn't block anything. Rather, the [*Same-Origin Policy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) places restrictions on cross-origin network access and CORS allows you to selectively lift those restrictions.